# How to parse json with persian keys?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a json string that contain some keys and values.In this case key's of json is persian character like *"شماره قرائت قبلی"*.

```
{قطر انشعاب آب":"1/2اینچ","شماره قرائت قبلی":4123"}
```

I had a try to parse this json string as normal way as below but doesn't work.

`var additional = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AdditionalModel>(extraInfo);`

My AdditionalModel class is :

```
public class AdditionalModel
{
    [JsonProperty("شماره قرائت قبلی")]
    public string NoRead { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("قطر انشعاب آب")]
    public string Diameter { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anyway to parse this json string?

Thank you.

Comment: Any JSON library can do this - `Newtonsoft.Json` is the main JSON library if you're targeting ASP.NET MVC - but use `System.Text.Json` if you're on .NET Core.

Comment: "not working." means more concrete?

Comment: Your code example is incomplete. You should include the AdditionalModel type and the extraInfo content. I'm pretty sure you could deserialize the Json in your example as a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Comment: The string you posted has a numeric string (4123) with a string value containing Persian characters, not the other way around. Numeric keys aren't allowed in JSON.

Comment: Your json snippet has the keys and values interchanged - the keys go on the left side of the colon, the values on the right

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. [It works fine with Persian keys](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hPs8fN).

Comment: @JonasHøgh that's correct, it contains persian characters, so keys and values will be interchanged https://dotnetfiddle.net/gUF8CD

Comment: @shingo I'm pretty sure the keys go on the left in Json regardless of whether the data is in a right-to-left language

Comment: @JonasHøgh have you check my link? It's working and the first WriteLine shows that the keys are on the right.

Comment: @shingo I'm afraid my browser is not fully RTL-capable and it cannot really make sense of your code (a quote is misplaced so that it looks like your string literals are unterminated). But I guess I get the gist of it. That's...mildly unsettling...

Comment: Hi @JonasHøgh , i saw your link and try that code but in my program (Under .Net 7.0)  does not work, however the code in your link work very well.

Comment: It also works in Visual Studio. In console/VS, the json string (as well as the parameters of `dict.Add(...)`) was LTR, but when I copied it to here, it became RTL. So the question is, what exactly is the original json you have? Checking its binary representation will be more accurate.

Comment: A direct copy/paste of your JSON gets me the characters  ` ` ` ` ` ` `{` `ق` `ط` `ر` ` ` `ا` `ن` `ش` `ع` `ا` `ب` ` ` `آ` `ب` `"` `:` `"` `1` `/` `2` `ا` `ی` `ن` `چ` `"` `,` `"` `ش` `م` `ا` `ر` `ه` ` ` `ق` `ر` `ا` `ئ` `ت` ` ` `ق` `ب` `ل` `ی` `"` `:` `4` `1` `2` `3` `"` `}` so your text is completely reversed

Comment: Any of these should work: `string extraInfo = "{'شماره قرائت قبلی':'4123' , 'قطر انشعاب آب':'1/2اینچ'}";`  or `string extraInfo = "{\"شماره قرائت قبلی\":\"4123\" , \"قطر انشعاب آب\":\"1/2اینچ\"}";` or `string extraInfo = "{\"شماره قرائت قبلی\":4123 , \"قطر انشعاب آب\":\"1/2اینچ\"}";` . Check the exact value of externalInfo.